# Buzzer with LEDs

Tags: batteries, switches, led-strip, buzzer

Does anyone know a basic circuit so I can have a switch which activates a buzzer and a LED strip run off a battery?
[image]

Comment: What battery do you want to use?  Which buzzer?  LED light strip?  Do you want them to only be on when the switch is pressed?  Do you want to the switch to turn them on with one press and off with another press?  This could be as simple as just connecting everything to a switch or it could be a bit more complex but we can't help if we don't know what is being hooked up.

Comment: Sorry, the type of led strips you cut, I’ve cut it down to small length of 6 leds. Small buzzer, it’s got Abi-001-Rc on it; sorry but I’m somewhat new to this. Possibly a AA battery or similar in size, Hope this helps more. I’ve included a picture of the led strip & buzzer above, thanks.

Comment: connect the buzzer directly to the battery ... if it makes a sound, then cut one of the wires ... touch the cut wire together, and the buzzer should sound ... that is your switch ... install a real switch where the wite is cut

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The LED strip is clearly labelled as 12 V so you'll need a 12 V supply.

The buzzer will work from 3 V to 16 V so you can use this on the same supply as the LED strips. See [Farnell](https://ie.farnell.com/pro-signal/abi-001-rc/buzzer-piezo-4khz-90db-16vdc/dp/1022392).

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fRnqfC.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. Battery, switch, buzzer and two sections of the 12 V LED strip.*

Observe required polarity of the battery, buzzer and LED strip.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: @Emz, you are welcome. Note that on SE sites you give thanks by upvoting useful answers and accepting the one that gives the best answer. That marks the question as answered so it doesn't keep popping up in the unanswered questions list.

Comment: All done ☺️